# How to use mysql database in android

Tags: android, mysql, database

I want to know how to use MySQL database with Android. Is there any sample program? Any website?

Comment: If you want a local database on the device, you would like to use SQLite. If you want to interact with MySQL one of the most common uses is to use PHP, device would communicate with PHP server using json and PHP server communicate with database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Follow the links :

http://itweb-projects.com/wordpress/android-connecting-to-mysql-using-php

http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/connecting-mysql-database

these may help you to understand "How to use mysql database in android" .